# get all tuples with maximum second value

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

How to fix the number of occurrence in a list of tuples and return an item with max value.

```
        given = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5)]

        expected = [('c',5),('a',3),('b',3)]
```

How do you do this without doing anything to complex.

Comment: Can you show what your complex solution was?

Comment: how can you sort the values from highest to lowest

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = groupby(sorted(given, key = lambda x: x[0]), key = lambda x: x[0])
print [max(g) for k,g in groups]
```

results in

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 5)]
```

Comment: You don't need to sort. Also `max` can take a lambda callback

Comment: @smac89 OP tagged `sorting`, so I'm assuming it needs to be sorted.

Comment: groupby needs a sorted item list because it looking for contigious items . max can take lambda, but I dont see how it serves the purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
given = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5)]
expected = dict(sorted(given)).items()
```

## Explanation

#### `sorted(...)`

When you sort the list, all the items with a low value (second element) are moved to the front of the list.

#### `dict(...)`

When you convert the sorted list to a dict, the lower values are replaced by the higher values which are closer to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward approach is to group the tuples in a dictionary, then just get the maximum `(letter, number)` value from each `letter` key in the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

given = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in given:
    d[key].append((key, value))

>>> print(dict(d))
{'b': [('b', 3)], 'a': [('a', 2), ('a', 3)], 'c': [('c', 5), ('c', 5)]}

>>> print([max(x[1], key = itemgetter(1)) for x in sorted(d.items())])
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 5)]
```

Without using external libraries:

```
given = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5)]

d = {}
for key, value in given:
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append((key, value))

>>> print(d)
{'b': [('b', 3)], 'a': [('a', 2), ('a', 3)], 'c': [('c', 5), ('c', 5)]}

>>> print([max(x[1], key = lambda x: x[1]) for x in sorted(d.items())])
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 5)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        given = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5)]
        expected = dict(given).items()
        dict_items([('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 5)])
```

Comment: doesn't work for `[('a',2),('b',5),('c',5),('a',3),('c',5),('b', 4)]`. You need to sort the list before hand, like @smac89's answer.

Comment: is there another way of doing defaultdict without collections